# mysql_real_escape simply making text blank

Tags: php, get, echo, mysql-real-escape-string

I am writing a little PHP-MySQL interface -- However, when I try to escape strings using mysql_real_escape, they are getting wiped blank!

Let's say we have a PHP file at the url

```
http://web/file.php
```

The contents of this file are:

```
echo $_GET["action"];
echo  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["action"]);
```

Now, let's say we load the url:

```
http://web/file.php?action=asdfqwerty
```

The FIRST echo will output "asdfqwerty".

However, the second one outputs nothing at all! I'm not sure why this is... Can anyone help out? Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), `mysql_real_escape_string` needs an open database connection. If none exists, an error occurs. You seem to have your PHP configured to not output errors, so you can't see this. You can verify it by using a higher error level:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo $_GET["action"];
echo  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["action"]);
```

Or by adapting your **php.ini**.

Answer (score 3):

mysql_real_escape_string needs an established mysql-connection. You probably don't have one and hidden errors of type E_WARNING.

```
php > echo mysql_real_escape_string('asd');
PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'timwolla'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in php shell code on line 1
PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in php shell code on line 1
```

Comment: Ooooh interesting, I was filtering my inputs BEFORE opening the connection

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen Then please accept the answer that helped you most and upvote other useful ones.

Comment: Works like a charm! Any chance I can get some trivia on why exactly it requires a connection?

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen The function reads information from the mysqld about what is needed to escape with the current charset.

Comment: I wanted to test before I accepted, not to mention I'm not able to accept until about 4 minutes from now EDIT: Thankyou for letting me know why!

Answer (score 1):

You either need an open mysql connection or the ability for mysql to open a connection. See [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) documentation under link_identifier

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP documentation, `mysql_real_escape_string` is used for *binary* data, while `mysql_ escape_ string` is used for regular string values.

If that doesn't work either, it means you are not establishing any connection to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have established valid mysql connection before?

If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

Answer (score -2):

Try to put your $_GET in a variable like:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
echo $action;
echo mysql_real_escape_string($action);
```

It works great on my local server...

Comment: $_GET['action'] is correctly passed to the script as the first line shows.

Comment: Try to put your $_GET in a variable like:

    $action = $_GET['action'];
    echo $action;
    echo mysql_real_escape_string($action);

It works great on my local server...